# Whats does $\varphi^*S$ mean?

Tags: linear-algebra, quaternions

The following formula is stated in the paper *Quaternionic Structures on a Manifold and Subordinated Structures*, written by D.V. Alekseevsky and S. Marchiafava:

> $$
> Aut(S)=\{\varphi\in GL(V): \varphi^*S=S\},
> $$

where $V$ is a finite-dimensional real vector space and $S$ is what the authors call a *quaternionic-like* structure on $V$. In particular, I am interested in quaternionic structures on $V$, i.e. a three-dimensional vector subspace $Q\subset End(V)$ spanned by three almost complex structures $I,J,K$ satisfying the quaternionic relation $IJK=-id_{4n}$.

Then, the question is, **what does the asterisk mean on $\varphi^*S$**? I guess it is just conjugation: $\varphi^*S=\varphi S\varphi^{-1}$, but I am not sure and I wanted to ask you.

Notice that in my case $Aut(Q)$ must be the group $GL(n,\mathbb H)Sp(1)=(GL(n,\mathbb H)\times Sp(1))/\mathbb Z_2$ acting on $V$ as

$$
(A,q)\longmapsto Avq, \quad v\in V.
$$

Thanks.

Comment: If ${\rm Aut}(Q)$ is indeed $GL(n,\Bbb H)Sp(1)$, then $\phi^{\ast} S$ must indeed be the space $\phi S\phi^{-1}$ obtained by conjugating every element of $S$ by $\phi$. (Note, because of the $Sp(1)$ factor, this means $\phi$ can permute elements of $S$, since quaternions don't usually commute with other quaternions.) Also, technically $GL(V)$ is not a vector space, and does not contain any vector subspaces since $GL(V)$ doesn't contain $0$. But yeah, $Q$ ought to be spanned by the $\{I,J,K\}\subset GL(V)$.

Comment: Good point, $GL(V)$ does not be a vector space. If I want to regard $Q$ asa vector subspace, it must be considered in $End(V)$. I will fix it now. On the other hand, if you want to add some details to your comment (e.g. how $GL(n,\mathbb H)SP(1)$ arises) and post it as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A=\mathrm{Aut}(S)$ be the set of all $\Phi\in\mathrm{End}_{\mathbb{R}}(V)$ such that $\Phi S\Phi^{-1}=S$, where $S=\mathrm{span}\{I,J,K\}$.

Define the following three elements of $S$:

$$ U=\Phi I\Phi^{-1}, \quad V=\Phi J\Phi^{-1}, \quad W=\Phi K\Phi^{-1}. $$

Since $\{U,V,W\}$ has the same multiplication table as $\{I,J,K\}$ within the quaternion subalgebra $H$ generated by $I,J,K$ (so, spanned by $S$ and scalar multiples of the identity), there must exist a "unit quaternion" $\Psi=a1+bI+cJ+dK$ (where $a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2=1$) in $H$ for which

$$ U=\Psi I\Psi^{-1}, \quad V=\Psi J\Psi^{-1}, \quad W=\Psi K\Psi^{-1}. $$

(This follows from properties of the quaternions $\mathbb{H}$, in particular how they're used to model 3D rotations by conjugating pure imaginary quaternions by unit quaternions.)

Therefore, the function $\lambda(X)=(\Psi^{-1}\Phi) X(\Psi^{-1}\Phi)^{-1}$ acts as the identity on $\{I,J,K\}$ hence on the entire subalgebra $H$. That is, $\Lambda=\Psi^{-1}\Phi$ commutes with $I,J,K$ hence $\Lambda\in \mathrm{GL}(n,\mathbb{H})$ (picking an $n$-basis for $V$ as a module over $H$), and therefore $\Phi=\Psi\Lambda\in \mathrm{Sp}(1)\mathrm{GL}(n,\mathbb{H})$.

Note $\mathrm{Sp}(1)\mathrm{GL}(n,\mathbb{H})$ and $\mathrm{GL}(n,\mathbb{H})\mathrm{Sp}(1)$ are the same thing, since elements of $\mathrm{GL}(n,\mathbb{H})$ by definition commute with scalars in the group $\mathrm{Sp}(1)$ of unit quaternions.

Comment: Nice answer. Let me ask you a little doubt before accepting it. You get $GL(n,\mathbb H)Sp(1)$ multiplying elements in the former by elements belonging to the latter. Thus, I guess that $A\in GL(n,\mathbb H)Sp(1)$ acts on $v\in\mathbb H^n$ simply as $Av=Qqv$, $Q\in GL(n,\mathbb H),q\in Sp(1)$. However, as far as I know, $GL(n,\mathbb H)Sp(1)$ is only a sorthand for the group $(GL(n,\mathbb H)×Sp(1))/\mathbb Z_2$ acting on $v$ as $Qvq$. How would you ''fix'' that? Do you know some reference where this stuff is explained with a high level of detail? Thank you.

Comment: Given two commuting subgroups $H$ and $K$ of a group $G$, the product $HK$ is a subgroup of $G$, the intersection $H\cap K$ is central in $HK$, and the multiplication map $H\times K\to HK$ is a group homomorphism with kernel $$ \{ (x,x^{-1}) \mid x\in H\cap K\}.$$ Therefore, by the first isomorphism theorem, $HK$ is isomorphic to the quotient $(H\times K)/(H\cap K)$, which is also called the [central product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_product) of $H$ and $K$, or denoted $H\times_{A}K$ (where $A=H\cap K$), similar to pushouts and amalgamated products.

Comment: In your case, $H=\mathrm{GL}(n,\Bbb H)$ and $K=\mathrm{Sp}(1)$ are commuting subgroups of $G=\mathrm{GL}(4n,\Bbb R)$ with intersection $A=H\cap K=\Bbb Z_2$ (up to isomorphism), so the "external" central product $\mathrm{GL}(n,\Bbb H)\times_{\Bbb Z_2} {\rm Sp}(1)$ you're talking about matches the "internal" central product $\mathrm{GL}(n,\Bbb H){\rm Sp}(1)$ in my answer.